# Blacks screen issue on AMD machine

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, gpu-driver, amdgpu

I just cannot install ubuntu 22.04.1 on my hp laptop running on amd cpu&gpu
Black screen issues all the time
I installed it and after cpuple restarts it just boots intoa black screen and nothing really happens then. Btw i made a dual boot with win 10

Comment: On what step are you getting stuck in the installation process? Have you been able to boot Ubuntu on your USB?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)